# Java program passes by several lines of code and goes to finally

Tags: java, exception

I wish I could find a better title...Anyway I get this very strange behavior, the program basically does this (without unnecessary details):

```
 try {              
            //...does something
            HashMap parameterMap = new HashMap();
            //Connection setup    
            try{                
                //...does something
                try {                   
                    //...does something
                    System.out.println("MESSAGE 1");
                    Report rpt = new gr.modus.ws.sepe.Report(parameterMap, connection);//Here seems to be the problem
                } catch( Exception e ) {
                    System.out.println("MESSAGE 2");
                }
                System.out.println("MESSAGE 3");        
                //...does something
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println("MESSAGE 4");                
            }
            System.out.println("MESSAGE 5");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("MESSAGE 6");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {           
                System.out.println("FINALLE");
                //...does something
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();                
            }
        }
```

also the **Report** constructor has nonting unusuall:

```
public Report(HashMap map, Connection con) {
        System.out.println("INSIDE");
        //...does something
}
```

When running the program in the development environment (from Eclipse, with WildFly 8) it's all good. I get:

```
MESSAGE 1
INSIDER
MESSAGE 3
MESSAGE 5
FINALLE
```

BUT when running in production environment (Weblogic server) I strangely get

```
MESSAGE 1
FINALLE
```

How is that even possible? Am I missing something?

- If there is **no** exception why "INSIDER" or "MESSAGE 3" isn't
  printed?
- If **there is** an exception in line "Report rpt = new ..."
  why is it never been caught by the catch blocks?

Edit: There is no error in log, nothing between those lines

```
<Sep 29, 2015 12:43:39 PM EEST> <Notice> <Stdout> <BEA-000000> <MESSAGE 1> 
<Sep 29, 2015 12:43:39 PM EEST> <Notice> <Stdout> <BEA-000000> <FINALLE>
```

Comment: an Error was thrown...

Comment: You don't need a try/catch in your finally block.

Comment: Did you check logs at prod?

Comment: @Prince Mani Gupta yes, see my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get an Error (or Throwable which is a super class of both Exception and Error), then catch Exception will not catch it.

Uncaught Throwables will usually be logged by the container server logs.

Comment: I see no error in log (see my edit), could it still be such an error?

Comment: Try catching Trowable instead to see if something else than an exception is thrown.

Comment: You were right, catching Trowable (in the last catch) worked. Not that it matters but the error was "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment"

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is throwing any Error,put catch block with Error e and print the error message to see the details.